# High memory usage to load google map in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, swift4

I am trying to develop an uber like iOS app. I just created a login page and map loading page. I have integrated google map and google places API. When running my app in simulator ,the debug navigator shows that the memory usage is around 300 MB. is there any memory leak in my app? or is 300 MB needed to load google map?

Answer (score 3):

Like Nathan mentioned 300 MB for the google map is pretty normal. The important thing is that this memory is getting released when you don't show the map anymore. If it is getting released and memory usage falls after not showing the map anymore, everything is fine i guess.

Answer (score 0):

it's completely  normal but don't forget to do this in `viewDidDisapper` to make memory usage lesser

```
        mapView.clear()
        mapView.removeFromSuperview()
        mapView = nil
```